# Como eu coloco o valor de uma variável dentro de uma textbox?

Tags: c#, string, label, double

Pessoal eu estou com um problema chato. Eu queria colocar o texto que eu tirei de uma textbox e colocar em outra que esta definida como readonly. Queria que funcionasse como uma label. Tentei textchange deu erro.

```
 private void btncalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         string salario = txtsalario.Text;
         double salario_num = double.Parse(salario);
         double liquido = (salario_num * 0.12);
         double conta = (salario_num - liquido);


      }
```

Sou leigo no assunto por isso queria saber o que posso fazer. Não sei se o que estou tentando fazer é válido por isso, tentei fazer com uma label mas também encontrei complicações. Alguém tem uma luz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma `TextBox` mesmo quando definida com o atributo `ReadOnly` a `True` pode ter o seu texto alterado programaticamente modificando diretamente o campo `Text`:

```
nomeDaMinhaTextbox.Text = "outro texto aqui";
```

Ou como no seu caso, vindo de uma variavel previamente construida:

```
nomeDaMinhaTextbox.Text = conta.ToString(); //.ToString() se for um int ou double
```

O que o `ReadOnly` faz é impedir o utilizador de escrever na `TextBox` como normalmente seria possível.

No entanto, se o utilizador nunca vai poder alterar diretamente o que está na `TextBox` e é só para visualização o melhor seria utilizar uma `Label`. A forma de atribuir o texto na `Label` é exatamente igual a uma `TextBox`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e esclarecimento :D